# Cannot import data from Access to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ssis

I am trying to migrate a vb.NET project from an MS Access database to MS SQL Server, and have been following a tutorial I found [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp) to do so. I did this, but got a problem where I could read data from the SQL Server database when running my project, but could not insert/edit data using the project.

Any data I tried to manipulate only worked on the Access database, and didn't have any affect on the SQL Server data (I also tried vice-versa, adding data using SQL Server but this couldn't been seen in my project). 
So I decided to try again, deleting the Access and SQL Server databases, and using the backup database to import the data from. However, this now is not working, and I'm getting the following error message

> Error 0xc020801c: Source - ~TMPCLP123581 [1](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp): SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Does anybody know a fix for this? Or why I can no longer import data into SQL Server? (The image below shows the result of what processes were/weren't carried out)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v6.0 for Access?
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43690

Comment: Have you checked [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627376(v=sql.105).aspx) article about this error? Possible Causes are listed there.

Comment: @gofr1 I've just checked and I cannot see that it could be any of these, I closed any programs that might be using the database, I'm on the PC admin account so access rights shouldn't be a problem either

Comment: @vercelli Hi, I managed to migrate the tables and all of their data over to SQL Server this way, so thank you, however when I run the program and try to open a form that should display the data, it says `ODBC--connection to 'SQL Serverserver\sqlexpress' failed` Any ideas?

Comment: @David I meant that you should try that product, SSMA for Access. It works really well.

Comment: @vercelli Yes, sorry I got the comments the wrong way around... See above comment, I have tried this but have another issue now

Comment: @David can you telnet port 1433? Is the firewall open?

Comment: @vercelli How do I run this test if my ip for the server is NULL?

Comment: @David How are you connecting you application to the server if the server doesn't have an IP?

Comment: @vercelli We (the company I work for) have multiple applications running off the server, for different companies, so it must work somehow, but after running a query to get the IP it returned NULL

Comment: @David well, if the vb.net application it's outside the server, you should have a way to access it. What connection string are you using?

Comment: @vercelli at the moment it's reading a connection from an ini file, which would take it to the access database. The connection string is `Public Sub openCon()
        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source="
        dbSource = readIni("CONTRACTSTRING", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini")
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue now, guys.

I migrated it over using Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access, and then changed the connection path and settings in my `.ini` file.

Then I created a new connection string, using string variables for each of the settings in the `.ini` file, and this replaced the initial Access database connection string.